# Proxy Reverse - Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I can not make my connection work.

On my server I have all the code of my project in AngularJS in the following location:

```
/var/www/html/web/site
```

My apache2 configuration file is located at:

```
/etc/httpd/conf
```

(I have other projects working correctly)

The virtualhost I use is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName webtest.stover.int
        ServerAlias webtest.stover.int
        RedirectMatch ^/$ /web/site
</VirtualHost>
```

If I do not understand wrong, I am saying that, when entering webtest.stover.int I redirect to

```
/var/www/html/web/site/index.html
```

Which it does correctly but it gives me a permission error:

```
You do not have permission to access /web/site/index.html on this server.
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just set the web dir to the location, proxies are used to proxy connections, in your instance you don't need that

Answer (score 3):

**Using the following steps:**

1) Update virtual file:-

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  ProxyRequests Off Order deny,allow Allow from all
 <Location />
        ProxyPass http:// mysite.com:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http:// mysite.com:8000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**2) Enabling Necessary Apache Modules**

To enable these four modules, execute the following commands in succession.

sudo a2enmod proxy

sudo a2enmod proxy_http

sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer

sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests

**3) To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.**

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Hi @Rajeev! The exactly error is: (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/web/site/index.html

Comment: Give permission?

Comment: The whole project has chmod 777 permissions and the owner and owner group are root root

Comment: You have enabled the rewrite mode " sudo a2enmod rewrite"? If not please run this command, After that run the restart apache2, and please share the screenshot.

Comment: And permission like a command: chmod -R 777 project name

Open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Look for the line that says

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>